# Syntax Confusion in C

Tags: c, syntax

I have been trying to figure out why my code keeps on saying that there is an error on line 5. I have checked it multiple times yet I am not sure what syntax is wrong with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void drawTriangle(int size){
        for(int i=1; i<=size; i++){
                for(int j = 1 ; j <=size-i; j++){
                        printf(" ");
                        for(int j = 1; j <= 2*i-1;j++){
                                printf("*");

                                }printf("\n");
                        }
                }

}



 int main(void ){
 drawTriangle(1);
 drawTriangle(5);
 drawTriangle(6);
 return 0;
}
```

The error explains that there is a syntax error on line 5 near unexpected token '(' and also on line 5 which says 'void drawTriangle(int size){'

Comment: Can't reproduce; `gcc -Wall -std=c99 test.c` emits no warnings.

Comment: Please tell us which line the error is on, as well as the exact and complete build log is.

Comment: I have compiled it with no errors. It's when I try to execute it, that it gives me errors

Comment: So is it a build error (like you say in your question) or a runtime error (crash) as you say in your comment? It can't be both.

Comment: If it fails at runtime (which I can't reproduce either), it wouldn't be a syntax error.

Comment: How come the compiler detects no error but some runtime system detects one in the **source code**? Sounds illogical.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1. What errors?
2. You might want to use a different variable name for the inner `j`. You've used that already so use `k`.

Comment: copied your code and compiled it, I didn't see any errors. I am on Mac by the way.

Comment: when running the command ./test.c it gives me the errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to run the C source as a shell script, and that won't work. You first have to *compile* the source into an object file, *link* the object file into an executable program, and *then* you can run the finished program.

I suggest you try these commands:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c test.c -o test.o
$ gcc test.o -o test
$ ./test
```

For simple programs like yours, which are only one or two files, then you can compile and link in one command:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 test.c -o test
$ ./test
```

---

By the way, it's usually a bad idea to name an executable program in a POSIX environment (like Linux or OSX) `test`, because there's a standard shell command called `test` as well, and if you write `test` instead of `./test` you will most likely use the standard program and not your own.

Comment: Note: he'll need to add the `-std=c99` flag to compile this particular code.  Suggest using `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: `$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 test.c -o test && ./test` will execute the binary if compilation succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run your source file as executable:

```
./test.c
```

That's not how it works.  You need to *compile* your source into an executable and run that.

```
gcc -std=c99 -o test test.c
./test
```